# WebServlet urlpatterns get Parameters

Tags: java, servlets

in Servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(name = "SinglePost", urlPatterns = {"/post/*"})
public class SinglePost extends HttpServlet {

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //do something...
    }

}
```

basic: example.site/SinglePost?id_post=123, and in doGet method:

```
id = request.getParameters("id_post");
```

but now, how to get id_post in doGet when visit throw url: example.site/post/123

Answer (score 2):

Your `id_post` is sent as a path element, not as a request parameter.

You'll have to use `HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()` and/or `HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()` to extract that part of the URL.